# Word meaning indifferent but with strong opinions on both sides

Tags: single-word-requests

For instance, "I'm *blank* to eating peanut butter for lunch because I really love the taste however I always end up with a mild allergic reaction afterwards."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Ambivalent* has this meaning. Or rather it can have this meaning. It means that you have opposing thoughts or feelings at the same time. These can be strong or weak, but in any case they are of approximately equivalent strength. In other words, they oppose and more or less balance each other, but they do not cancel each other: each is still present (and is thus felt or thought).

- *I am ambivalent about eating peanut butter for lunch. On the one hand, I love the taste; on the other hand, I often have a mild allergic reaction to it.*

Comment: +1. For a more casual choice of words, "have mixed feelings about" is commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

Less formally than ambivalent, there is the the expression 'to be on the fence.'